# Error AT command for getting number phone

Tags: vb.net

Please .. i really need help to solving this problem ..
With my mobile .. manually i type this code ( *99# ) to display my number phone .. and this message will appear without any problem (MSISDN: 21677245978) ..
I wanted to get my number phone with this code :

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.SerialPort1.PortName = "COM5"
    Me.SerialPort1.BaudRate = "1200"
    If Not (Me.SerialPort1.IsOpen = True) Then
        Me.SerialPort1.Open()
    End If

    Me.SerialPort1.Write("AT+CUSD=1," & Convert.ToString(Chr(34)) & "*99#" & Convert.ToString(Chr(34)) & ",15" & System.Environment.NewLine)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000)
    Me.RichTextBox1.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Me.SerialPort1.ReadExisting, "(?<=\:).+").Value.Trim

End Sub
```

But unfortunately the last two digits number phone does not appear and i get this result in my RichTextBox1 (MSISDN: 216772459, 15)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but probably increase the "34" from Convert.ToString(Chr(34)).
By the way I am not that experienced but try trial and error on anything that you think the code can be changed just try it.

Comment: Thank you .. i tried like this but  .. any command .. I have not any result .. Textbox is empty (     Me.SerialPort1.Write("AT+CUSD=1," & "*99#" & ",15" & System.Environment.NewLine)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000)
        Me.RichTextBox1.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Me.SerialPort1.ReadExisting, "(?<=\:).+").Value.Trim )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Any suggestion please .. ??

Comment: I'm not sure I think you might have to re ask the question. Sorry